# How to play (13 kb/s) .wav file in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I couldn't play (.wav - 13 bit) file in aspx page.I've tried Html5 player , embedding mediaplayer in html and SoundPlayer in asp.net. I dont want to convert my wav file. Is there any Solution to play ? Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Background:**

```
<embed src="bgsound.wav" hidden="true" autostart="true" loop="1">
```

**On Click:**

```
<a href="success.wav">Play Sound</a>
```

http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/mark/audio/play.htm
Have you try this?

Source: [Best way to play wav files in the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175448/best-way-to-play-wav-files-in-the-browser)