# JavaScript Audio is not working in safari 5.1.7 an IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, audio, safari

I have an Wav audio file which i want to play it when window loads.

Its working in firefox, chrome, opera, But not working in IE and Safari.

**javascript**

```
var sound = null;

window.onload = function(){

  sound = new Audio("/sound/longType.wav");
  sound.addEventListener('canplaythrough', function() { 

            sound.play();

  }, false);
}
```

**Error** I am getting in Safari is

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a constructor (evaluating 'new Audio("/sound/longType.wav")')
```

**Error** I am getting in IE is

```
AUDIO/VIDEO: Unknown MIME type
```

Why this error in safari ? Please point me in right direction.

Answer (score 0):

#### The MIME type error tells everything

Safari does not play audio by itself. It needs QuickTime installed on Windows. Do that, and probably will work.

#### Solution

You cannot play every sound format in every browser, so maybe you should consider to choose the correct file type by checking the browser support of this file type.

Very useful examples for this check can be found [here](http://diveintohtml5.info/everything.html).

Maybe this is also interesting for your case: [Best way to play wav files in the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175448/best-way-to-play-wav-files-in-the-browser)

Additional Info: [Media formats supported by the HTML audio elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats)

Comment: but i have mime-type set for wav file in my web.xml

Comment: I modified my code to use .aac audio in IE which is supported, but still the same error persist

Comment: @shadow - Does it work without javascript? (Using the plain html <audio> element)

Comment: I changed it again to .mp3 and now its playing using plain html

Comment: Thanks buddy for help,  I fixed issue for IE but the major problem is in safari

Comment: @shadow - Which version of Safari do you use?

Comment: @shadow - Are you testing on a local machine? Maybe the problem is located at your webserver which serves the audio files with a wrong mimetype or something like this.

Answer (score 0):

To play audio on safari browser while click event, follow up this steps :-
1) If audio not play while click over play button, then
  a) After Install Quicktime player in system.
  b) When we click over play button, if audio play, then ok. otherwise we will get an error "'undefined' is not a constructor (evaluating 'new Audio()')"
  c) close safari browser if opened.
  d) Copy QTFC.dll from "C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem" to "C:\Windows\System32"
  e) Open safari browser again and audio play on click event.
If still not,then let me know..