# How to receive wav file from flask server in Swagger?

Tags: python, flask, audio, swagger, wav

I don't play wav file (audio) in swagger.

I have a flask server and write swagger.yaml file about server.

flask server return wav file like this

```
@app.route("/tts", methods=["POST"])
def generateTTS():
    if request.method == "POST":
        input_text = request.form["input_text"]
        batched = request.form["batched"] 

        input_text = preprocessing(input_text)

        wav_file = getTTS(input_text, batched)
        save_path = wav_file[1]
        wav_file = wav_file[0]
        
        return send_file(save_path, mimetype="audio/wav")
```

and my swagger file ( version 3.0.0 )

```
paths:
  /tts:
    post:
      requestBody:
        required: true     
        content:
          multipart/form-data:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                input_text:
                  type: string
                batched:
                  type: boolean
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Success
          content:
            audio/wav:
              schema:
                type: string
                format: base64
```

I tried to change response '200' schema type `format: binary` `format: byte` `format: base64`

If I use curl then I can receive wav file but If I try out in swagger, I don't play wav file and download wav file.

How to receive and play wav file in swagger?

Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: Swagger defines the API endpoint and I am guessing you are using the simple/automatically generated web interface that it provides, if you are doing this in the browser you will need to [add additional markup to play a wav file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175448/best-way-to-play-wav-files-in-the-browser) (please also refer to linked and related questions in that thread). Please update your question to include additional details as to what exactly you want to do because the question as is now does not have your full intent.

Comment: I use swagger editor. I found out that browser receive well wav data but audio src value is not audio but url that browser send requests. so, after post request browser send "GET" request one more time. then get 405 error. how can I input wav data in audio src?